# How to know when a textbox changes (without waiting for blur)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<input>` textbox.

I wish to call a function when it has been modified. The default behavior of the `change` event is to only trigger on `blur`, but I need to call my function as soon as the textbox's text changes and can't wait for `blur`.

I'm not sure the best way to do this. I thought of maybe handling `keydown` and then testing the value of the keyCode for a key that would modify the value. So... ignore arrow keys, etc. But that seems awkward and I don't think I can figure out the test to make it work.

I also thought about recording the inital value and comparing to this value but then I wouldn't be notified in the case when the value changes back to the original.

Maybe there's a better way?

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a combination of `focus` and `keyup` is probably your best bet. record the initial value in the `focus` handler, and check against the current value in the `keyup` handler. (the new input value, if any, is available when `keyup` fires).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [keypress function](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [change() function](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: ie fires change just before blur so no good in this situation